# An upper bound of number of some fractional ideals

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

Consider a number field $K$ of degree $n>2$, and an order $\mathcal{O}\subset \mathcal{O}_K$ on it. Let $I(\mathcal{O})$ be the monoid of $\mathcal{O}$-fractional ideals modulo principal fractional ideals. Consider the function

$$f: I(\mathcal{O}) \rightarrow I(\mathcal{O}), J\mapsto J^n$$

Do you know upper bounds

$$|f^{-1}(J)|\leq c(n)  \;\;\forall J\in I(\mathcal{O}) 
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{($|\cdot|$ is the cardinality of a set)}$$

for some constant $c(n)$ depending only on the degree $n$? I'm not looking for an optimal upper bound. I'm most interested in the case $n=4$.

Answer (score 3):

For any $n > 2$, there is no such upper bound. Consider for simplicity the case that $\mathcal{O} = \mathcal{O}_{K}$. If you take $J$ to be the identity class, then $f^{-1}(J)$ is the set of elements of order dividing $n$ in the class group. The question then is - for any $n \geq 2$, is there a uniform bound on the $n$-torsion subgroup of the class group?

Let $\ell$ be a prime dividing $n$ and consider cyclic extensions $K/\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $\ell$. If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ ramifies at $d$ primes, it follows from a Theorem of Hasse that the $\ell$-rank of the class group is $\geq d-1$. (See the theorem referenced on the bottom of page 86 of the paper "On the 3-class groups of cyclic cubic extensions of certain number fields", which can be found [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=25&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbxYyBvvXTAhVO7GMKHTyDD6E4FBAWCDcwBA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2F0022314X7690024X%2Fpdf%3Fmd5%3D0eec8b56ab3a19a7252d40cf3c6239bf%26pid%3D1-s2.0-0022314X7690024X-main.pdf%26_valck%3D1&usg=AFQjCNE6PGTJLWavdD3yHEywntUDhmAxoA).) It is not hard to show that there are cyclic extensions that ramify at arbitrarily many primes. (If $p_{1}$, $\ldots$, $p_{k}$ are primes $\equiv 1 \pmod{\ell}$, for each $i$, $1 \leq i \leq k$ we choose $H_{i}$ to be the unique subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/p_{i} \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ of index $\ell$, and for each $i$, let $\chi_{i} : (\mathbb{Z}/p_{i}\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ be a character for which $\ker \chi_{i} = H_{i}$. Now, define $H = \{ x \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times} : \prod_{i} \chi_{i}(x) = 1 \}$. This $H$ has index $\ell$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. Using the isomorphism $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})/\mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, we get that $H$ corresponds to a subfield of $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})$, and the conductor-discriminant formula implies that $K$ ramifies at all primes dividing $n$.)

This constructs an $\ell$-extension $K$ where the $\ell$-torsion in the class group can be arbitrarily large. If now $L/K$ is a totally ramified degree $n/\ell$ extension, then the class group of $L$ has the class group $K$ as a quotient (by class field theory). It follows that $L$ is a degree $n$ number field, and the $n$-torsion in the class group of $\mathcal{O}_{L}$ can be as large as you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the cardinality of $H$ is $\ell^k$?, or maybe I dont understand very good the definition of $H$

Comment: I think my definition of $H$ isn't quite right. I'm going to edit the question.